# Pivot Table Filter to show only blanks gives Error in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have coded to created and add fields to a pivot table and the only thing left is to add a filter for 'Date Terminated'. I have added the filter OK but to filter I need it to show (blanks) only and have tried variations on a dozen of so methods I have been looking into online - please help.

```
Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, "System Report!R1C1:R" & SystemReportLastRow & "C49")
Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(Sheets("Top Accounts").Range("A2"))
```

'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

```
Sheets("Top Accounts").Activate
Range("A2").Select

Set objField = pt.PivotFields("ACCOUNT_NAME")
objField.Orientation = xlRowField
objField.Subtotals(1) = False



Set objField = pt.PivotFields("LINE_LASTBILLAMT")
objField.Orientation = xlDataField
    objField.Function = xlSum
    objField.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 [$kr.-da-DK]"

Set objField = pt.PivotFields("ITEM_SERIAL_NUM")
objField.Orientation = xlDataField
    objField.Function = xlCount
    objField.NumberFormat = "#,##0"

Set objField = pt.PivotFields("LINE_ACC_AMOUNT")
objField.Orientation = xlDataField
    objField.Function = xlSum
    objField.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 [$kr.-da-DK]"

Set objField = pt.PivotFields("ACCOUNT_NAME")
objField.AutoSort _
        xlDescending, "Sum of LINE_ACC_AMOUNT"

Set objField = pt.PivotFields("DATE_TERMINATED")
    objField.Orientation = xlPageField
    objField.Position = 1

PivotField.PivotItems("*").Visible = False
PivotField.PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a working solution:

Dim p_i As PivotItem
With pt.PivotFields("DATE_TERMINATED")
.PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = True
For Each p_i In .PivotItems
If p_i.Name <> "(blank)" Then
p_i.Visible = False
End If
Next
End With